# How to extract zipcode from very meshy string using regular expression in SAS?

Tags: regex, sas

I am trying to extract 5 number zipcode from the address field. I have included the sample data (see below). The data has 5 digit street fields in the beginning, and also 5 digit PO Box number in the middle part and 5-9 digit zipcodes, some in middle part and some in the end of the string. my objective is to extract the 5 digit zipcode from the string but not the 5 digit street and PO Box number using regular expression in SAS. Please take a look at the sample data and help me resolve this issue. I would highly appreciate your kind assistance.

```
13001 NW42 AVE OPA LOCKA FL 33054 USA
13001 NW 42 AVENUE OPA LOCKA FL 33054 USA
PO BOX 98748 CHICAGO IL 60693 USA
601 W 80TH STREET CHICAGO IL 60620 2502
12651 S DIXIE HWY, SUITE 321 MIAMI,FLORIDA33156
12713 SW 125TH AVE MIAMIFL 331865932
```

Comment: Do you want only 5 digit ones from the end, or if it is using the 9 digit zip, you want that 9 digit extracted as well? So like `12713 SW 125TH AVE MIAMIFL 331865932` would extract `331865932` and `601 W 80TH STREET CHICAGO IL 60620 2502` would extract `60620 2502`?

Comment: is the pun intentional?

Answer (score 1):

This would work for your specific example.

```
data have;
length str $150;
infile datalines truncover;
input @1 str $150.;
datalines;
13001 NW42 AVE OPA LOCKA FL 33054 USA
13001 NW 42 AVENUE OPA LOCKA FL 33054 USA
PO BOX 98748 CHICAGO IL 60693 USA
601 W 80TH STREET CHICAGO IL 60620 2502
12651 S DIXIE HWY, SUITE 321 MIAMI,FLORIDA33156
12713 SW 125TH AVE MIAMIFL 331865932
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
z_Re = prxparse('`(\d{5}) ?(?:$|USA|\d{4})`o');
rc_z = prxmatch(z_re,trimn(str));
if rc_z then zip = prxposn(z_re,1,str);
put zip=;
run;
```

You can either adjust that to include other things, or do some reasonability checks for the possible places a 5(+) digit string might appear that is a zip code.  For example, you might require it to be within 10 characters of the end-of-string, and at least 10 characters from beginning-of-string:

```
data want;
set have;
z_Re = prxparse('`^.{10,}\D(\d{5}).{0,10}$`o');
rc_z = prxmatch(z_re,trimn(str));
if rc_z then zip = prxposn(z_re,1,str);
put zip=;
run;
```

I have to include a \D to make sure it matches 33186 instead of 65932 in the last match.  This rule may be better or may be worse depending on your various other possibilities; depending on your data it's possible no match is good enough to catch 100%.  You might consider doing both methods, and looking at the records where they disagree.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dataset that comes with all SAS installations called SASHELP.ZIPCODE.  It contains a pretty up to date list of all US zipcodes (or you can download the most recent from the SAS site [here](http://support.sas.com/rnd/datavisualization/mapsonline/html/misc.html)).  Simply extract anything that looks like a 5-digit zip then bash it against the list.

If you want to be extra careful, you could pull the statename (or state abbreviation) from the zipcode table and make sure that the name of the state can be found somewhere in the string containing the zip also.